# How to send message in websocket connected to my server from Quectel EC20 through AT Commands?

Tags: serial, at-commands, tcp-ip

I made a Websocket connection from Quectel EC20 after opening TCP connection by giving IP and PORT and after that I sent GET req where header upgrade to websocket through AT Commands but I am not able to send anything after that as I want to send JSON message to my server but not able to send anything so please help me I got stucked in this...

Comment: There’s an arduino library for that. Look at how they do it.

Comment: can you please mention the link of that arduino library

Comment: Google ec20 arduino. I gather you’ve read the ec20 datasheet - what does that say you need to do?